# Python convert list of objects to list of one object parameters

Tags: python, list

I have a list of group objects which have several attributes include: name, size, etc.
Is it possible to from this list derive a list containing one of their parameters. Ex:

```
l = [<Group1>, <Group2>, <Group3>]

# some command to get 
l2 = [Group1.name, Group2.name, Group3.name]
```

Assuming a Group object has a .name attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
l2 = []

for element in l:
    l2.append(element.name)
```

OR using list comprehension:

```
l2 = [element.name for element in l]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in 1 step?

Comment: @MattStokes, Did that help? If not, do you have any other questions? If it did, would you mind accepting it? Thanks.